# Warning in IOS build while validating app

Tags: ionic-framework

**How to remove warning _setAlwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority in IOS?**

```
Always found this warning when I am trying to release my app to app store. Can any one have experienced of it please help
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience, It's a warning you can ignore it still if you want to resolve this warning you need to update your **webview plugin** to the latest version and this will remove above warning.

**Follow the below steps:**

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

Will install the latest version of WebView Plugin and after onwards you will not get above warning.

[Ref Link of this warning reported](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/209)

Hope this will helps!